# Need assistance setting mask layer anchor point

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, mask

```
CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
mask.contents = (id)[[self getImg]CGImage];
mask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.vview.frame.size.width, 100);
mask.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);
self.vview.layer.mask = mask;
```

I am trying to set mask on my `UIView` `vview`, `vview`is 300 in height but when I set `anchor point` mask layer jumps up around 50px, what should I do to maintain its original position.

[image: vview in green without any masking]
vview in green without any masking

[image: vview in green with masking but no anchor point]
vview in green with masking but no anchor point

[image: vview in green with masking and anchor point]
vview in green with masking and anchor point

Comment: could you add screen shot ?

Comment: @Or.Ron please view the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about anchor point:

```
anchorPoint
 Property
Defines the anchor point of the layer's bounds rectangle. Animatable.

Declaration
SWIFT
var anchorPoint: CGPoint
OBJECTIVE-C
@property CGPoint anchorPoint
Discussion
You specify the value for this property using the unit coordinate space. The default value of this property is (0.5, 0.5), which represents the center of the layer’s bounds rectangle. All geometric manipulations to the view occur about the specified point. For example, applying a rotation transform to a layer with the default anchor point causes the layer to rotate around its center. Changing the anchor point to a different location would cause the layer to rotate around that new point.

For more information about the relationship between the frame, bounds, anchorPoint and position properties, see Core Animation Programming Guide.
```

Geometry manipulations: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html

Based on that if you don't want to move the mask you just need to set the anchor point as

```
mask.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
```

That is the default value.

Comment: Yes I need to set the  anchor point because I also animating the mask, if I don't change the anchor point the animation is performing from the center, I want to animate from bottom, thats why I changed the anchor point.

Comment: Can you check the value of the position property?. That would be probably different of what you are expecting. Also your frame is changing after you set a different anchor point. You may need to recalculate the frame/bounds/position taking that into account.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am asking for :)